# Turtle Graphics - Alternate Colors of Letters in Words

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I have a list of colors:

```
colors = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow"]
```

and I would like to display text using `turtle.write()` to alternate the colors of the letters in the words "DOG" and "ALLIGATOR".

The letters of "DOG" would be colored "red", "blue", and "green"

The letters of "ALLIGATOR" would be colored "red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "red".

How can this be done in Turtle Graphics? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of things that should make this easier to implement.  The first is to use `itertools.cycle()` to repeatedly work through your list of colors.  The other is to use the `move=True` argument to `turtle.write()` so that you can print the individual characters of the words one right after the other:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
from itertools import cycle

FONT = ('Arial', 36, 'normal')
COLORS = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow"]

def stripe_write(turtle, string):
    color = cycle(COLORS)

    for character in string:
        turtle.color(next(color))
        turtle.write(character, move=True, font=FONT)

yertle = Turtle(visible=False)
yertle.penup()

stripe_write(yertle, "DOG")
yertle.goto(100, 100)
stripe_write(yertle, "ALLIGATOR")

screen = Screen()
screen.exitonclick()
```

[image]